# How do I post tweets to my own twitter application using the Twitter supplied token/secret?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have no problem using OAuth to authenticate another user to send tweets on their behalf, but I am drawing a COMPLETE blank when it comes to posting tweets to my own timeline.

Our auth settings are as follows:

[image]

Twitter supplies your access token and access token secret here:

[image]

However, after I create the client using our consumer key and secret, and try to post using the access token/secret, I keep getting an error that the Access token has expired

Can anyone help shed some light on this? What do I need to do to simply have my web app post tweets to my own twitter timeline?

**EDIT: UPDATE**

This is the response I get from my request:

```
object(HttpResponse) {
    body => '{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}'
    headers => array(
        'content-length' => '61',
        'content-type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'date' => 'Thu, 09 Jan 2014 04:16:41 UTC',
        'server' => 'tfe',
        'set-cookie' => 'guest_id=v1%3A138924100123005834; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 09-Jan-2016 04:16:41 UTC',
        'strict-transport-security' => 'max-age=631138519',
        'Connection' => 'close'
    )
    cookies => array(
        'guest_id' => array(
            'value' => 'v1%3A138924100123005834',
            'domain' => '.twitter.com',
            'path' => '/',
            'expires' => 'Sat, 09-Jan-2016 04:16:41 UTC'
        )
    )
    httpVersion => 'HTTP/1.1'
    code => '401'
    reasonPhrase => 'Unauthorized'
    raw => 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-length: 61
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 04:16:41 UTC
server: tfe
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A138924100123005834; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 09-Jan-2016 04:16:41 UTC
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
Connection: close

{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, apparently I made the rookie mistake of not updating all my tokens after I regenerated the application to be read/write instead of just read.